# How to count all folder ,file and files in sub folder in server using php?

Tags: php, file, directory

How to count all folder ,file and files in sub folder in server using php ?

i want to count all files ,folder and files in sub folder in path `/home1/example/public_html/`

First i use this code

```
<?php 
$directory = "/home1/example/public_html/";
$filecount = 0;
$files = glob($directory . "*");
if ($files){
 $filecount = count($files);
}
echo "There were $filecount files";
?>
```

it's show `There were 561 files`

And then i use this code

```
<?php 
$fi = new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
printf("There were %d Files", iterator_count($fi));
?>
```

it's show `There were 566 Files`

And last i use this code

```
<?php 
    // integer starts at 0 before counting
    $i = 0; 
    $dir = '/home1/example/public_html/';
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
            if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
                $i++;
        }
    }
    // prints out how many were in the directory
    echo "There were $i files";
?>`
```

it's show `There were 500 Files`

But result were difference.

I was test by create file in `/home1/example/public_html/images/` But all result still show same like before i create file.

How can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Your second example will return a more precise answer than the first because `glob` ignores hidden files and `FilesystemIterator` does not.

The big difference in the third example is that in #1 and #2 you are iterating and then counting both files and directories, where as in #3 you are filtering directories in the count (by calling `is_dir`).

So #3 is probably correct (except for what I mention in the NOTE below), and I would suggest using a variant of #2 which will be much easier to read:

```
function recursive_file_count($dir)
{
    $fi = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $c = 0;
    foreach ($fi as $fileInfo)
    {
        if (!$fileInfo->isDir()) { ++$c; }
        // can also test for $fileInfo->isLink() if needed
    }
    return $c;
}
```

NOTE: The count is also affected by filesystem permissions.  So for example if this script is running in Apache under the httpd user, and the httpd doesn't have execute permission on a certain directory, it won't be able to enter that directory and count its files.  There is no way to solve that without some sort of evil privilege escalation hacks.